# How do you use a Bootswatch theme in Angular 5

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular5, bootswatch

I am trying to use a Bootswatch theme in an Angular 5 project.  I am using both Bootswatch and Bootstrap versions 4.0.0-beta-2.  I have installed both via npm and have imported the _variables.scss and _bootswatch.scss in my styles.scss using the usual angular-cli/webpack conventions in my main styles.scss.  I also import the relevant theme bootstrap.min.css into this file, and I add it to the styles[] array in angular.cli.json.

During build I get:

```
@include box-shadow(none);
        ^
     No mixin named box-shadow
```

and a broken build.

Comment: try like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootswatch

Answer (score 12):

You are working with angular 4-5. so `npm install bootswatch` and attach the related libraries in `style.scss` file as described.

You are not including the libraries in order.
Try importing it like this.

`@import "../node_modules/bootswatch/dist/materia/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "../node_modules/bootswatch/dist/materia/bootswatch";
@import "../node_modules/bootswatch/dist/materia/bootstrap.min.css";`

Comment: I'm not sure if ```@import "../node_modules/bootswatch/dist/materia/bootstrap.min.css";``` is required

Comment: materia/bootstrap.min.css is not the same as the vanilla bootstrap.min.css, I would include it.

Comment: Adding Bootstrap styling to a project in Angular 15 and this still works.